After update to 24.04 what do "System Problem" reports mean?
After a very painful upgrade to 24.04, boots and updates often have a "System Problem" box with "ignore" and "report" choices. Zero information as to nature or substance of the problem. I never hear back about reports (the option I always choose) - what's going on?

Sending the report is not intended to suggest that a human will read the report and contact you. That's not what happens to the report. A machine reads the report and adds the information to https://errors.ubuntu.com . From there, it may become part of the workflow for developers and engineers working to fix various assorted problems.

The reports you send should be stored in your /var/crash directory. Review a few of them to determine what kind(s) of problem(s) your system has.

Thank you, User53...  I get it now.  (Review of crash reports is way beyond me.)
